# Wrap a crystal object into a custom root object in JSON

Tags: json, crystal-lang

I have a class like the following

```
class Foo 
  JSON.mapping(
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
  )
end
```

I know that I can wrap single attributes in JSON objects by specifying `{root: "name of node"}` inside of JSON.mapping. But is there any way to do it for the entire `Foo` class?

So that the output would look like this?

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "",
    "baz": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no method to do it, but you can do this:

```
require "json"

class Foo
  JSON.mapping(
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
  )

  def initialize(@bar : String, @baz : String)
  end
end

foo = Foo.new("r", "z")
json = {foo: foo}.to_json
puts json
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer! The only problem I have now is that my question was a bit too abstract :/ The problems seems to now lie in the fact, that my object is already a nested object inside something else I'm calling #to_json on. I tried the naïve way of overwriting #to_json and returning `{foo: self}.to_json`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Then why don't you use `root` for the field with `Foo` on the enclosing object?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to my comment, you can also overwrite the `to_json` method of `Foo`:

```
def to_json(builder : JSON::Builder)
  builder.object do
    builder.field "foo" do
      previous_def
    end
  end
end
```

https://carc.in/#/r/286q